# How Dojo FilteringSelect can have Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a select field where my option value is more than around 250 characters,and that is why users are not able to read the value in the select box.

Is there any way to make the select as horizontal scrolling or can i wrap the text.

Comment: 250 characters for an option's text... really ?

Comment: I am not even trying to answer this one... if your select box has over 250 characters, you should rethink what you want to put in that select box, not how to wrap it etc...

Comment: But seriously now. You can make the `<select>` as wide as you want, and the window will get a horizontal scrollbar, allowing the user to read everything. What is the problem? (Other than, as everybody has noted, a 250 character option text. And a horizontal scrollbar.)

Comment: It's having dynamic values i don't have control for the text coming in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is My Filter Select and a span Node which will act as dumy pane for the drop down.

```
<span dojoAttachPoint="dumyPane" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; float: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;">
<input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" dojoAttachPoint="myDrop" size="50" style="width:400px;">
```

Below is the code snippet to append my dropdown node to a the dumypane.

```
dojo.connect(myDrop, "openDropDown", this, function(val){
  dojo.connect(myDrop.dropDown, "onClick", this, function(){

 if(typeof  myDrop.dropDown != "undefined" &&  myDrop.dropDown !=null){         
    myDrop.setDisplayedValue(event.srcElement.innerText);                                               
    }

   });
     if(typeof  myDrop.dropDown != "undefined" &&  myDrop.dropDown !=null){ 
        var ddNode = myDrop.dropDown.domNode;                           
    dojo.style(ddNode,{overflowX: "scroll",overflowY: "scroll",width: "400px",height: "100px"});

   dumyPane.appendChild(ddNode);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width of a box with style attribute. The only problem is, you can not see the whole word. It cuts it off.

```
<select size="1" name="blah" style="width:250px">
```

My advice to you would be to try and limit the number of characters in the select field. 250 characters is rather long. You might also consider using a different input control.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have noted, you should rethink your UI, for the sake of your users.

However, if this is out of your control, the CSS [white-space](http://dochub.io/#css/white-space) property might help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters that you should probably rethink the UI. That said, if you're stuck with options that are that long, you could try the [chosen javascript plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). It basically hijack's a targeted select element and replaces it with a snazzy set of divs that act like a select element. But, you can style the div's however you please.